# Which one is correct? (Past simple vs Past perfect)

Tags: verbs, word-usage

I took an English test today and I wasn't sure about how to fill these gaps:

"After he ... his homework, he ... his bedroom."

finished/cleaned or had finished/cleaned, maybe another option?

Answer (score 1):

Both verb forms must be in Past Simple as the events are reported in a chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

The word ***after*** is sufficient to indicate that the former action took place before the latter. The past perfect would be redundant here. Thus, the correct answer would be:

> After he finished his homework, he cleaned his bedroom.

Comment: To me as a British speaker, the most natural version would be 'After he had finished his homework, he cleaned his bedroom' because the first action had to be completed before the second could start.

Comment: @KateBunting: Yeah, that works too.